# importing table of relations to NEO4J

Tags: neo4j

I have a table of relations (A sends email to B) in CVS format. How can I import it to NEO4J environment?
there should be something like loop in CQL environment. but I could not find.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `LOAD CSV` Cypher tool as documented here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html

If you have a CSV file of email addresses that represents `(:Person)-[:SENDS_EMAIL_TO]->(:Person)` like this:

```
"From","To"
"bob@loblaw.com","someone@else.com"
"someone@else.com","john@example.com"
```

You can import this into Neo4j with a Cypher script like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file.csv" AS row
MERGE (from:Person {email: row.From})-[:SENT_EMAIL_TO]->(to:Person {email: row.To})
```

For performance, first create a uniqueness constraint on `:Person(email)`:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.email IS UNIQUE;
```

You mostly likely want to use a bit more complex data model however, depending on your use case. If you have the content / metadata of the email you should consider extracting `Email` out into a node, so the data model would look more like this:

```
(from:Person)-[:SENT]->(E:Email)-[:TO]->(to:Person)
```

You can then store meta data of the email on the `Email` node.

Comment: Thanks for comment. but I tried and faced error:                                    Invalid input '{': expected whitespace, comment or a label name (line 2, column 62 (offset: 130))
"MERGE (from:Person {email: row.From})-[:SENT_EMAIL_TO]->(to: {email: row.To})"

Comment: I had left out a `Person` label in the query. Fixed now. Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks. it is resolved. I have another issue with loading data. Above table which I want to import in NEO4J has 700k rows and I face error : Java heap space. I tried changing the heap size by : #wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024 but did not worked. it could not even load 100k!

Comment: Add `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` to the beginning of the Cypher statement. See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data

Comment: Thanks. it solved the load issue. now after loading the data i want to delete it but due to the big size of that it gives again Java heap size error. When I add the USING PERIODIC COMMIT at the start of delete statement it shows error.

Comment: @Mahsoon try deleting in batches using `LIMIT` clause: `MATCH (a) WITH a LIMIT 10000 DETACH DELETE a`

Comment: again thanks. I need a for loop command to delete  the whole info. do you have any idea about putting above clause in loop?